# Re-release an app on the Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

A while ago I released an app on the Google Play Store, but it didn't go as expected. So, I'm planning on a re-write and would like to re-release it under the same store name.

Is it possible to remove the current APK, reset the store listing and start over with a new APK?

Comment: you can update the existing app, if you are interested to release the same app on play store then Login google play console -> select the app -> store presence -> price & distribution -> unpublish the app and submit it. after that rename applicationId and submit it as a new application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to ...
>
> remove the current APK

No. Once an app / APK has been uploaded, you can't remove it. You can upload a newer version over it (i.e., push an update) but once a version of an app is published to Google Play, they own a copy forever and the history of the activity for that app remains.

> reset the store listing

It's unclear what you mean by "reset the store listing". You can edit the store listing to change all of the details, sure, to reflect the new version of the app. You cannot blow away the existing data to pretend the first version of the app never happened, however.

> and start over with a new APK?

You cannot "start over". Once an APK with a specific package name has been uploaded, that history persists. You can upload an update with the same package name and all of your changes and update the store details to make the app look like something new / different, but the history will remain.

Otherwise, you would have to upload your APK as a new app with a new package name to truly "start over".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks dominicoder for clearing this up. I was hoping I could clear the history and start again, but it seems the best approach is to upload the re-write and change the store listing to reflect this new version.